# # R - Create new matrix of only newly changed values, else insert NAs

Tags: r

In R language, I want to create a new matrix of only newly changed values, else insert NAs.

t12 below has correct logical answer, but I need code to get t12desired, please.

```
t1<-matrix(c(1,2,1,3,1,4),ncol=3,byrow=T); t1
t2<-matrix(c(1,1,1,3,1,4),ncol=3,byrow=T); t2
t12<-t2!=t1; t12 
t12desired<-(matrix(c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA),ncol=3,byrow=T)); t12desired
```

Comment: could you give a an example where this is more useful than  a simple `t1 == t2` boolean matrix?

Answer (score 4):

We can compare the datasets and then with `NA^` returns NA for all TRUE and 1 for FALSE

```
NA^(t2 == t1)
```

---

It is a bit unclear whether the OP wanted 1s and NAs (for nonmatching cases) or replacing the original matrix 't2' where it is not matching with 't1' to NA (as @Onyambu mentioned).  If it is the latter

```
`is.na<-`(t2, t2==t1)
```

or multiply with 't2' (if it is numeric matrix)

```
NA^(t2 == t1) * t2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do:

```
# Step 1: Get values if equal or not (vector)
vals = sapply(t2 == t1, function(x) ifelse(isTRUE(x), NA, 1))


# Step 2: Convert to matrix
mat = matrix(vals,nrow = 2,ncol = 3)
print(mat)

     [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    1   NA
[2,]   NA    NA   NA
```